# 'Queue' object has no attribute 'size'

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, queue, attributeerror

I have seen other examples of this happening on StackOverflow, but I didn't understand any of the answers (I'm still a new programmer,) nor did the other examples I saw look quite like mine, else I wouldn't post this question.

I'm running Python 3.2 on Windows 7.

I have never had this happen to me before and I've done classes this way many times, so I don't really know what is different this time. The only difference is that I didn't make all of the Class file; I was given a template to fill in and a test file to try it on. It worked on the test file, but is not working on my file. I have been calling on the methods in the class in the exact same way as the test file (e.g. `Lineup.size()`)

This is my Class:

```py
class Queue:
    
    # Constructor, which creates a new empty queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__items = []
        
    # Adds a new item to the back of the queue, and returns nothing:
    def queue(self, item):
        self.__items.insert(0,item)
        return
        
    # Removes and returns the front-most item in the queue.  
    # Returns nothing if the queue is empty.
    def dequeue(self):
        if len(self.__items) == 0:
            return None
        else:
            return self.__items.pop()
        
    # Returns the front-most item in the queue, and DOES NOT change the queue.  
    def peek(self):
        if len(self.__items) == 0:
            return None
        else:
            return self.__items[(len(self.__items)-1)]
        
    # Returns True if the queue is empty, and False otherwise:
    def is_empty(self):
        return len(self.__items) == 0
    
    # Returns the number of items in the queue:
    def size(self):
        return len(self.__items)
    
    # Removes all items from the queue, and sets the size to 0:
    def clear(self):
        del self.__items[0:len(self.__items)]
        return
        
    # Returns a string representation of the queue:
    def __str__(self):
        return "".join(str(i) for i in self.__items)
```

This is my program:

```py
from queue import Queue

Lineup = Queue()

while True:
    decision = str(input("Add, Serve, or Exit: ")).lower()
    if decision == "add":
        if Lineup.size() == 3:
            print("There cannot be more than three people in line.")
            continue
        else:
            person = str(input("Enter the name of the person to add: "))
            Lineup.queue(person)
            continue
    elif decision == "serve":
        if Lineup.is_empty() == True:
            print("The lineup is already empty.")
            continue
        else:
            print("%s has been served."%Lineup.peek())
            Lineup.dequeue()
            continue
    elif (decision == "exit") or (decision == "quit"):
        break
    else:
        print("%s is not a valid command.")
        continue
```

And this is my error message when I enter "add" as my decision variable:

*line 8, in 
builtins.AttributeError: 'Queue' object has no attribute 'size'*

So, what is going on here? What is different about this one?

Comment: it seems you are importing the builtin `queue` module rather than your own. Try checking what `queue.__file__` is set to.

Comment: Python 3 already contains a `queue` module. Rename your `queue.py` to `my_queue.py` and your code should work.

Comment: Oh wow... how did I not notice that? haha. Thank you. That fixed it.
You should "answer this question" so I can give either of you a thumbs up and a checkmark.

Comment: If you don't want to fall into custom code you can also try `from collections import deque` which is similar to lists but very efficient, and will get you the job done.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Python 3 already has a `queue` module (which you might want to take a look at). When you `import queue`, Python finds that `queue.py` file before it finds your `queue.py`.

Rename your `queue.py` file to `my_queue.py`, change your import statements to `from my_queue import Queue`, and your code will work as you intend.

Answer (score -3):

try rename size for other name or implement a counter to the list __items some like

```
def get_size(self):
    cnt = 0
    for i in self.__items:
        cnt++
    return cnt
```